# Is there a way to insert 500 records into sql server in 1-2 seconds using python

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to perform some operation post which the resultant dataframe will have 500-700 records and i would like to load this data to a sql server table in 1-2 seconds.

Comment: 700 rows in more that 2 seconds would be awfully slow. A good server could done several 10's of thousands, or more, in a matter of milliseconds.

Comment: How are you trying to insert them at the moment? I *assume* you're using an RBAR approach, and why this is slow.